# How to download single project from repository?

Tags: git, github, download

In normal, when I want to download a project from github, I can choose "download as Zip" or "Clone in Desktop" at the right sight of Web Browser like this:
[image]

But in some repository, there are a lot of projects and I don't want to download all the projects. I just only want to download one of them. but when I klick one of them I didn't saw the download button or similar. How can I download all files in single project instead of downloading all projects in repository?: I just want to download all file in this:
https://github.com/ioscreator/ioscreator/tree/master/IOS8SwiftAddSearchTableViewTutorial
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this can't be done via the website or git, at least from my knowledge.

However, you can download a subdirectory from Github using Subversion.
[CoderWall with example, by a guy named Janos Gyerik](https://coderwall.com/p/o2fasg/how-to-download-a-project-subdirectory-from-github)

Example given from link:

```
svn export https://github.com/janosgyerik/jquery-upvote/trunk/lib jquery-upvote-lib
```

Comment: A proposed edit to my post was rejected because it made it unclear, given that the extra example that was to be added does not perform the task asked by the question, rather it was shown to inform how to download the entire project rather than the subdirectory.

Comment: I can do it using svn export and change the link to download and use terminal, here is my terminal:svn export https://github.com/ioscreator/ioscreator/trunk/IOS8SwiftAddSearchTableViewTutorial and It's worked!!